# Formik is not removing values that are not in yup schema

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

Let's say I have this initial values

```
{animal: "rhino", parts: {legs: 4, horns: 0}}
```

and in my yup schema:

```
animal = yup.object().shape({
   animal: yup.string().oneOf(["dog", "cat", "deer", "rhino"])
   parts: yup.object().when("animal", value => {
      switch(value) {
         case "dog":
         case "cat":
            return yup.object().shape({
                parts: yup.object().shape({
                   legs: yup.number().required()
                })
            });
         case "deer":
         default:
            return yup.object().shape({
                parts: yup.object().shape({
                   legs: yup.number().required(),
                   horns: yup.number().required() 
                })
            });
      }
   })
});
```

Whenever I submit the form with `dog` or `cats` as animal, `horns` is still included in the submitted data. Is there a way for yup or formik to automaticall remove it on submission?